# Visual Studio - Can I debug my app on a CE device over the network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce

I am developing an app for Windows CE with Visual Studio 2008.

If I connect the device via USB I can debug / deploy my app on the device.
But on the CE device the USB connection is just presented as another network interface with a private IP.

Now I am wondering If it is possible to dismiss the USB connnection an connect over the LAN (both my PC and the CE device are on the same subnet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I do this at work. First you need to run IPConfig on the device and get the IP. Setup the IP in visual studio's connection properties. Next there are two executables and some files you need to copy to the device.. here this should explain

[How to: Connect to Windows CE Device Without ActiveSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Just execute those two exe's and you should be able to connect. BTW, debugging over ethernet is much faster and less buggy than activesync