# Why am I getting "Win32Exception" with this code?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, versioning

From what I understand based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181093/how-does-one-designate-the-root-of-a-handheld-device) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186198/why-is-this-function-returning-nothing-although-there-is-a-match), my app is running from a location that can be referred to with @"*\Program Files\HHS\HHS.exe*":

[image]

...and the file I want to access could be accessed via @"\Application\sscs\HHSetup.exe":

[image]

...but this code:

```
string clientVer = HHSUtils.GetFileVersion(@"\Application\sscs\HHSetup.exe"); 
. . .
public static string GetFileVersion(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        const int VERSION_DEPTH = 4;
        var version = NativeFile.GetFileInfo(filePath);
        return version.Version.ToString(VERSION_DEPTH);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

...fails. Instead of a version number such as "3.1.4.7"  (or something sensible like "0.0.0.0" as a "can't find it" value), GetFileVersion() returns "*Win32Exception*."

Even when I deal with that by forcing such an "oh, well" value:

```
if (clientVer.Contains("Exception")) 
{
    clientVer = "0.0.0.0";
}
```

...the subsequent call fails with "Unable to connect to the remote server"

```
// both serial num and clientVer have valid values now, such as "8675309" for serialNum and "0.0.0.0" for clientVer
string uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/FileTransfer/GetUpdatedHHSetup?serialNum={0}&clientVersion={1}", serNum, clientVer);
RESTfulMethods.DownloadNewerVersionOfHHSetup(uri);
```

...but that's another story; my question here is: Why does GetFileVersion() return "Win32Exception"? Is the path I am sending (@"\Application\sscs\HHSetup.exe") wrong, or is it something in GetFileVersion() itself?

### UPDATE

Since the code is almost guaranteed good, I'm thinking the problem must be in the path I'm passing in - it's format or such. Maybe it *is* a permissions error, as Michael Kniffen supposes below; but if so, I don't know how to solve it. Or maybe it's a path formatting issue? I don't know; I'm more stumped than a 19th century Oregon homestead...

### UPDATE 2

It seems to be a path issue; czech this out:

```
//string clientVer = HHSUtils.GetFileVersion(@"\Application\sscs\HHSetup.exe");
// to see if the path is the problem, try something more straightforward:
string clientVer = HHSUtils.GetFileVersion(@"\Program Files\HHS\vsd_setup.dll");
```

The commented out code was causing the problem.

The new code runs okay; I get a valid file version ("1.0.2268.0").

So it almost has to be either the path ("\Application" is not correct for accessing the "Internal Flash Drive" (or whatever the correct terminology is)) OR maybe the file itself - it doesn't have file version information, so that being the case might be the cause of the problem.

I'll test this by copying vsd_setup.dll beneath the sscs folder and trying this:

### UPDATE 3

It was the file - the test works fine. So if a file doesn't have version information, a Win32Exception 13 is returned.

If the file being sought has version info, I get it (such as "1.0.2268.0"); if it doesn't, though, watch out below - all Dallas breaks loose!

```
string clientVer = HHSUtils.GetFileVersion(@"\Application\sscs\vsd_setup.dll");
```

Comment: More than likely this is a permissions error. Try setting the file permissions on the file to "Full Access" for "Everyone" and see if it resolves your problem

Comment: Get in the habit of **not** using try/catch until you understand what it does.

Comment: Did you get your `NativeFile.GetFileInfo` call from the link below? It  looks like it passes in the reason when throwing the exception. You'll need to look at the actual error code specified in the exception. http://blog.opennetcf.com/2010/09/28/getting-native-file-info-in-the-compact-framework/

Comment: @HansPassant: I believe I understand try/catch well enough (not as well as you, granted). I don't see the benefit of not having it. It *is* returning the "Win32Exception" which is more info than I'd have without it, right?

Comment: Bizarrely, the Win32Exception has "gone away" with no change to the code...I still get the "Unable to connect" err msg, though.

Comment: @MichaelKniffen: From Windows Explorer, I don't see this (set File Permissions") option on files on the handheld device. The file in question has for properties only "General" and "Details" tabs. "General" has "Read-only" and "Hidden" checkboxes, both of which are clear/unchecked.

Comment: @TyCobb: I mean, "Yes, I did" get the code from the link you posted. How to look at the actual error code, though?

Comment: Apparently because the Win32Exception is constructed with the native error code, the `Message` should be telling you what is wrong. Can you post what the message is? I didn't see it when I looked earlier and you are returning it in your code.

Comment: @TyCobb: All I was getting was "Win32Exception"; that has gone away, somehow. But it still doesn't work; I don't know if that's because never the twain shall meet between Compact Framework and Web API, or what...

Comment: @TyCobb: To be more precise, GetFileVersion() is still failing, because clientVer is being set to "0.0.0.0", but I no longer see the "Win32Exception" message.

Comment: Were you running your application while it was attached to your PC? If so, do you have a virus scanner?

Comment: If you get the exception back, post the value of [Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.nativeerrorcode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Also, if you step through the code that @TyCobb pointed you to, how far do you get?

Comment: @PaulH: I cannot step through the handheld code - it's running on the device. I copy the exe to the device and run it from there. It *is* attached to the PC, but doesn't run in the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: @PaulH: As to "post the value of Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode", do you mean like this: 
"return ex.Message.GetTypeCode().ToString();" or how?

Comment: I mean: `catch (Win32Exception ex){ return ex.NativeErrorCode; }`
I'm not clear on why you can't use the VS debugger to step through this code. Can you explain?

Comment: @PaulH: I can't step through because there is no working emulator; I have to actually run the code on the device.

Comment: Okay...Why can't you use the Visual Studio debugger to debug the app on the device?

Comment: @PaulH: If that's possible, I don't know how. I gave up on that months ago after trying everything possible and posting many questions here.

Comment: @PaulH: return ex.NativeErrorCode.ToString() returns "13"

Comment: A delightfully unhepful error code. Okay, I recommend replacing the .netcf version of GetFileInfo() with the much longer one in the .netcf blog and filling it with lots of debug messages OR create a minimal version of your app that only does this one thing you're having problems with and try to reproduce it on the emulator with the debugger attached.

Comment: Is error 13 "ERROR_INVALID_DATA" - the same as that found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: @PaulH: Remember, I don't have an emulator. This code is from the Compact Framework Whisperer (ctacke), so I'm loathe to abandon it just yet.

Comment: This is definitely not a permissions problem.  Win CE doesn't have permissions.  if your code is running, it has permissions.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Get your debugger working. Here's how I do it over ethernet (if you have it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968547/visual-studio-can-i-debug-my-app-on-a-ce-device-over-the-network/12969064#12969064

I'm not sure what type of device you are using but you are sort of at the mercy of whether or not the OEM has included the necessary components in the windows image for debugging. Try that link though, it is easy enough. You copy several files, execute them, and then connect over ethernet with the IP

Comment: The device is a Symbol 3190; and I don't think they were very merciful.

Comment: @Alan: The link you provide is "How to Connect to Windows CE Device Without ActiveSync" but I do have ActiveSync working - the device is connected to my PC, I just can't debug, as there is no emulator available for the device.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Debug over activesync on the real device. You don't need an emulator, select 'windows ce device'

Comment: Select Windows CE Device where? I'm willing to try it, but I can't see I'm optimistic - I tried several months ago for quite awhile to get it to work and, as I was unsuccessful, and the previous developers (who have written and maintained this app for years) also were never able to do it, I really doubt that it's possible in our scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not start out with a simple app that you just run on the device that runs through the basics?  This will tell you if it's a path problem or not.  Not having a live debugger doesn't mean you should forego the debugging fundamental of "start simple".

```
public static void Main()
{
    var path = "\\my\\file\\path.foo";

    Console.WriteLine("Checking for file...");
    var fi = new FileInfo(path);
    if(!fi.Exists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting version...");
        const int VERSION_DEPTH = 4;
        var version = NativeFile.GetFileInfo(path);
        Console.WriteLine(version.Version.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + return ex.Message);
    }
}
```